# Unable to open files in octave GUI

Tags: homebrew, octave

I've updated to octave `4.1.0+` on my mac via homebrew.

Two (related?) problems that I'm seeing:

- Now when I type `octave` on a command line the Octave GUI opens fine, but I don't seem to be able to open any files (`.m` or otherwise). When I double-click a file nothing seems to happen, and there are no messages on the command line window, even if I use the `--verbose` switch to start it up.
- When I try to close the GUI's window, octave just blocks, and the only way I can get it to close is to kill the process on a command line.

**How can I debug this to understand what's going on?**

Comment: 4.1.0+ is the "default branch" which is also known as "development" branch and you can't expect that it's suitable for productive use. I would have a look at the log files and check if qscintilla was found and used. Can you open an editor window from the GUI by clicking "File New" are you able to save it? Just to be clear, with "double clicking a file" you mean inside the integrated file browser in the GUI, not in your system file browser, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I was double-clicking it on the integrated file browser. I was installing from head to work around an [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3669#issuecomment-244393926) with the current homebrew formula. Meanwhile I gave up on homebrew for octave and tried the [app buldle](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X) instead, and it worked fine.